# Getting Records with Different Criteria

Tags: oracle

I have an oracle query that i am using to collect records that have a buyer type code of VTEST
but i also need to populate records in the same query that have code matching ADULT but onlyt matching a particular sales channel.

the listed tables dont have a sales channel link but the transaction table does have sales channeland it can join to the event_seat table by the transaction_id field

so basically i want to pull records that match VTEST and ADULT but where as the adult ones can ONLY match the sales channel id of 6

any help is greatly appreciated

```
SELECT
    e.event_date,
    e.venue_id,
    e.description     AS event,
    t.price,
    t.ticket_id,
    bt.buyer_type_code,
    bt.description    AS buyer_type,
    btg.description   AS ticket_category,
    SUM(sci.actual_amount) AS tax,
    t.price + SUM(sci.actual_amount) AS revenue,
    e.event_id,
    coupon.coupon_code
FROM
    event e
    INNER JOIN event_seat es ON e.event_id = es.event_id
    INNER JOIN ticket t ON es.ticket_id = t.ticket_id
    LEFT JOIN service_charge_item sci ON sci.ticket_id = t.ticket_id
    INNER JOIN buyer_type bt ON t.buyer_type_id = bt.buyer_type_id
    INNER JOIN buyer_type_group btg ON bt.buyer_type_group_id = btg.buyer_type_group_id
    LEFT JOIN coupon ON t.coupon_id = coupon.coupon_id
WHERE
    e.event_date > '1-JAN-2022'
    AND e.description LIKE '%Testshow%'
    AND e.description NOT LIKE '%Join%'
    AND e.description NOT LIKE '%Left%'
    AND e.event_status_code = 'SAL'
GROUP BY
    e.event_date,
    e.venue_id,
    e.description,
    t.price,
    t.ticket_id,
    bt.buyer_type_code,
    bt.description,
    btg.description,
    e.event_id,
    coupon.coupon_code
HAVING
    bt.buyer_type_code LIKE 'VTEST'
```

Comment: Your data model and data is likely very clear in your own head.  Unfortunately, it is very hard for someone else to help without an understanding of your data.  Please edit the question to include a reproducible test case (table definitions, sample data, expected output).  Ideally, look at your query and see if you can reproduce the issue with less than 7 tables or with fewer columns to simplify the test case you need to create

Comment: i guess what i am really asking is how do i get the my reults to have VTEST which is sold by many channel_id's AND only records of channel_id 6 that are ADULT

Answer (score 0):

Considering you haven't done the joins and it's through 2 tables, I will leave this part to you, but you can implement the logic you describe by removing the `HAVING` clause and add in the where:

```
AND bt.buyer_type_code IN ('VTEST','ADULT')
AND 6 = CASE WHEN buyer_type_code = 'ADULT' THEN sales_tbl.channel_id --or whatever it's name is
             ELSE 6
        END
```